# Automatic database update when widget is reopened

Tags: qt

I have a widget that sits within a stacked widget and is used to display a database in a table. At the moment the database is populated and displayed within the constructor which is wrong as it only happens the once so never updates. So I am guessing there has to be a function that should be called for database updating.

So I am hoping there are functions that can be overridden for when widgets are closed or opened? But I am not sure what these are. I am sure it is something really obvious but I'm not having any luck finding them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I am hoping there are functions that can be overridden for when
>   widgets are closed or opened?

`showEvent(QShowEvent* event)` and `hideEvent(QHideEvent* event)`.  There is also a `closeEvent(QCloseEvent* event)`, but that probably isn't applicable for widgets in a stacked widget.